# Rails: How to include all associations with where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 6.1.4 and I have a Contact model having a has_one relationship with a Client model. A client has a status column.
However, Not all contacts have a client, but I want to return all contacts where clients have status as active, inclusive of contacts not having a client.
I tried this query but it only returns objects having a client associated.

```
@contacts = @contacts.eager_load([:client, :organization, :addresses]).where("clients.status = 'Active'").all
```

Can someone please help me with a query?

Comment: `.where(clients: {status: [nil,'Active']})` this will create a where clause of *"WHERE (clients.status IS NULL OR clients.status = 'ACTIVE')"*

Comment: @engineersmnky, if `Client#status` can be nil, by default or something, this will not return the correct records. Also, OP is asking for `contacts` without a `client`, not `contacts` where the `client`'s status is 'nil' or 'Active'.

Comment: @Chiperific your first comment is fair e.g. if a client status can be `nil` otherwise my suggestion works fine because the OP is asking for contacts where the client has no contacts or where it dies have contacts those contacts are active. If a status cannot be `nil` then the only way a joined client status can be NULL is if the client does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but should be headed in the right direction:

`@contacts.eager_load([:client, :organization, :addresses]).where("clients.status = 'Active'").or(where("contacts.client_id IS NULL").all`

Here's a trick I use: examine the SQL generated by your query:

`Contact.eager_load([:client, :organization, :addresses]).where("clients.status = 'Active'").to_sql`

And see what that gets you, then you can play with [`find_by_sql`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql):

```
Contact.eager_load(...).find_by_sql(
  SELECT ... FROM contacts
  JOIN ...
  WHERE contacts.client_id IS NULL
  OR clients.status = 'Active'
)
```

Comment: `.or(where("contacts.client_id IS NULL"))` is not valid and will raise. This would need to be compatible with the original query e.g. `.or(@contacts.eager_load([:client, :organization, :addresses]).where("contacts.client_id IS NULL"))` based on the way `or` works.